# How To Do nWAKE of a sensor in STM32

Tags: stm32

I need to reactivate a sensor before any communication. The device has its own pull up resistor and I have to set the nWAKE pin to 0, after the communication I have to leave the pin high. I used the ODR register to set the nWAKE pin to 0, but how can I release that pin after communication?

Comment: You can write 0 or 1 to ODR, but a better way is to write 1 to BSR (bit set register) to set the line high, and write 1 to BRR (bit reset register) to set the line low.  BSR and BRR can be written separately or together as a combined register BSRR.  In that case the low 16 bits of BSRR are for setting, the high 16 bits are for resetting.

Comment: @TomV thanks, but when I write into BRR is the corresponding output held to reset or the external pull up resistance will make it high?

Comment: Writing 1 to any bit in BRR sets the corresponding bit in ODR to 0.  If a pin is configured as an output and ODR is 0 then the voltage on the pin will be logical low.  If there is a pull-up resistor on the pin then the voltage will be a few millivolts above 0V, but it will still be logical low.

Comment: @TomV Ok thank you very much. So if I understand, I could set BRR to lower the nWAKE pin when communicating, then reset the BRR bit (writing 0) to release the pin to the pull up resistor. Correct?

Comment: No.  Writing zero to BRR does nothing.  Write 1 to BSR to set ODR to 1.  If ODR is 1 then the pin will either be driven high or released to the pull up register depending on the value of the MODER register.